# How to use my own icon set in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, assets

[image]

I have my own icon set like this, and I'm trying to import them in create-react-app. Importing them one-by-one in my component doesn't seem to be a good solution, as I have lots of icons. Should I bundle them in a single module and then import them, if yes, then how? How can I approach this task? Thanks. :)